# MIDI Bluetooth LE, SYSEX messages are not complete

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, midi, coremidi

Using the MIDI Bluetooth LE framework, I send this MIDI SYSEX message over Bluetooth:

> "F0H 26H 79H 0EH 7FH F7H"

I receive over Bluetooth:

> "F0H 26H 79H 0EH 7FH" (end of SYSEX is missing)

I have to add the end Byte programmatically, but I don't know, when then end occurs. Is this a bug in the framework?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the call back method. Now it works fine with the Yamaha MD-BT01.

Catches the MIDI In data and fills it in a ring buffer for later treatment:

```
static void MyMIDIReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist, void *refCon, void *connRefCon) {
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pktlist->numPackets; i++) {
    if (i == 0) packet2 = pktlist->packet[0];
    nBytes2 = packet2.length;
    iByte2 = 0;
    while (iByte2 < nBytes2) {
        inputByte2 = packet2.data[iByte2];
        inppoint2++;
        if (inppoint2 >= bufsize2){
            inppoint2 = 0;
        }
        inputBuffer2[inppoint2] = inputByte2;
        iByte2 ++;
    }
    packet2 = *MIDIPacketNext(&packet2);
}
```

}